# Is the timestamp not saved when someone subscribes to the newsletter?

Tags: newsletter

There is a field `change_status_at` which is a `TIMESTAMP` in the `newsletter_subscriber` table.  However it doesn't appear to be getting populated when newsletter subscriptions happen, or even when the subscription status changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `change_status_at` field is intended to hold the last date of subscription/unsubscription. However, this field is never be used or updated in Magento. (Maybe a bug in Magento).

If you inspect the core, you can find out that, this field is using to display in customer newsletter section (in admin under `Customer > Manage Customer`). However since this field is never be updated while processing subscription in Magento, the below section is never get rendered in customer section.

```
#Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Newsletter::initForm()

if($changedDate = $this->getStatusChangedDate()) {
     $fieldset->addField('change_status_date', 'label',
         array(
                'label' => $subscriber->isSubscribed() ? Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Date Subscribed') : Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Date Unsubscribed'),
                'value' => $changedDate,
                'bold'  => true
         )
    );
}
```

and `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Newsletter::getStatusChangedDate()` looks like this.

```
public function getStatusChangedDate()
{
    $subscriber = Mage::registry('subscriber');
    if($subscriber->getChangeStatusAt()) {
        return $this->formatDate(
            $subscriber->getChangeStatusAt(),
            Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true
        );
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here `$subscriber->getChangeStatusAt()` always return`null` for every customer. Hence condition fails and the method returns a `null` value. Thus the field to show the `Last Date of subscription/Unsubscription` never get rendered.

However, you can use the advantage of this field by adding a simple line of code inside `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::subscribe()`. You just want to do this before `$this->save()` action gets performed.

```
#Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::subscribe(), before save() action
$this->setChangeStatusAt(date('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: I am using 1.9.3.8 and this field is still not populated, would this be a suitable solution still?

Comment: @VaishalPatel Yes, you can use this.

Comment: Rajeev didn't work

Comment: How on earth is this still not fixed as of 1.9.4.2, when the fix is so trivial and there is code elsewhere that expects this to be populated?