# How to get Subscriber based on from date in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, newsletter, date

I am able to get all subscriber but there is no date filter in Magento for subscribers.

Can anyone tell me how to get subscriber based on date in magento?

Comment: newsletter subscribers do not store dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of RnD I found below free extension available on Magento connect to fix my problem. But this will help me in future. It cannot give old subscriber information. Because there is no date field or column in default Magento.

[Subscription fix extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/subscription-date-fix.html)

Answer (score 0):

The subscription date is not stored in Magento.

However, there is a way to store it yourself when a user signs up.

Just add:

```
$this->setChangeStatusAt(date('Y-m-d'));
```

to `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::subscribe()`, in the `beforeSave()` action

More info here: [Is the timestamp not saved when someone subscribes to the newsletter?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57550/is-the-timestamp-not-saved-when-someone-subscribes-to-the-newsletter)