# Magento 1.9.3.8 Saving Newsletter subscriptions and unsubscriptions timestamp

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I would like to have a timestamp stored for when a person subscribes or unsubscribes.

Looking at the database: specifically the table `newsletter_subscription` I see the field `changed_status_at`. However, this does not get populated, it is left null.

Evaluating the file **/app/code/core/Mage/Subscriber.php** I cannot see any reference to this field either.

Doing some research I found this [**link**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57550/is-the-timestamp-not-saved-when-someone-subscribes-to-the-newsletter). However, after placing the suggested solution on the line(s) 350 and 376 of **Subscriber.php** it makes no difference and was still unchanged. Thus, is this a bug in magento and if so how would I correct this?

### Update

After playing around with this, I placed `->setChangeStatusAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` before every save call in the file. For example,

```
$this->setSubscriberStatus(self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED)
            ->setChangeStatusAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->save();
```

This looks to be setting the changed status date now. But, I can only see it if I go to manage customers. Thus, how could I:

A) do this without editing core files?

B) show this date in Newsletter => Newsletter Subscriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have altered the **`newsletter_subscriber`** table and added the field to store the timestamp.

**Answer for part A:** By adding an observer to the event newsletter_subscriber_save_before in your config.xml:

```
<global>
    ....
    <events>
        ....
        <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
            <observers>
                <your_unique_event_name>
                    <class>yourgroupname/observer</class>
                    <method>newsletterSubscriberChange</method>
                </your_unique_event_name>
            </observers>
        </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

You can then call **getSubscriber()** (see next code block) in your observer to get the **`Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber`** model that allows you get data about the subscriber. This works for occurrences of subscription and unsubscriptions.

```
public function newsletterSubscriberChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
    //now do whatever you want to do with the $subscriber

    //for example
    if($subscriber->isSubscribed()) {
        //...
    }

    // Your code to set timestamp

}
```

**Answer of part B:** You can extend the newsletter subscriber grid using your custom module and add the new column to show the new field.

You may need to use join in the _prepareCollection() function if you have created a custom table instead of adding the column to the **`newsletter_subscriber`** table.

**Update:** To know more about extending Newsletter Subscribers Grid, please check the following link:

[Rewrite Admin Newsletter Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120110/rewrite-admin-newsletter-grid)

Comment: Nope mate the change_status_at is a default field magento just doesn't seem to be using. Would you have a god tutorial for how to extend the newsletter subscriber grid?

Comment: @VaishalPatel, please check my update in my answer.

Comment: I will do, shall test and accept accordingly if all works well.